# readline with console.log in the background

Tags: node.js

I'm having problems with node.js' readline. Shown below is the console output: the stuff in bold is what I am typing, the rest is what is being logged by the server.

```
> Teslog message
> Testinlog message
> log message
log message
Tlog message
estinglog message
> 123
```

Put simply, my code looks like this

```js
setInterval(function() { console.log("log message") }, 1000);
var cli = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
cli.setPrompt("> ", 2);
cli.on('line', function(line) {
    cli.prompt();
});
cli.prompt();
```

How can I get the prompt to shift down to give the new output room, without completely trashing whatever I am typing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to somewhat solve the problem - the prompt at least gets redrawn after the console is logged to.

```
var log = console.log;
console.log = function() {
    // cli.pause();
    cli.output.write('\x1b[2K\r');
    log.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    // cli.resume();
    cli._refreshLine();
}
```

<s>However, the interrupted prompt does not get cleared.</s>

**EDIT:** adding `cli.output.write('\x1b[2K\r');` made it work

---

**EDIT 2:** More complete solution, making other things like `util.log` work as well:

```
function fixStdoutFor(cli) {
    var oldStdout = process.stdout;
    var newStdout = Object.create(oldStdout);
    newStdout.write = function() {
        cli.output.write('\x1b[2K\r');
        var result = oldStdout.write.apply(
            this,
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        );
        cli._refreshLine();
        return result;
    }
    process.__defineGetter__('stdout', function() { return newStdout; });
}
```

**#EDIT 3:** Looks like `cli.pause()` and `cli.resume()` before and after the call are redundant.

Comment: Did you show those "more hacks"? You should show what did and didn't work quite like you wanted.

Comment: But please make it evident to people what didn't work and what did, that's all I'm asking.